# How do I declare an array of a derived type? (Julia)

Tags: julia

I have a derived type represented by:

```
struct BoundaryCondition
  domain::MeshStructure
  left::BorderValue
  right::BorderValue
  bottom::BorderValue
  top::BorderValue
  back::BorderValue
  front::BorderValue
end
```

I want to create an array of this derived type, of size n_comp, which I have in my code as:

```
bc = Array{BoundaryCondition}(n_comp)
for i in 1:n_comp
  bc[i] = createBC(m)
  bc[i].left.a[:] = 0.0
  bc[i].left.b[:] = 1.0
  bc[i].left.c[:] = c_left[i]
end
```

But I receive an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching (Array{BoundaryCondition, N} where N)(::Int64)
```

What is the correct way to declare my array of type BoundaryCondition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preallocate it, you need to fill your array with something. For example, you can use `undef` (replace the `Bool` type and size with those of your problem):

```
julia> Vector{Bool}(undef, 3)
3-element Vector{Bool}:
 1
 0
 0
```

You can also use `fill` (same, replace `false` with your problem's default "fill" value):

```
julia> fill(false, 3)
3-element Vector{Bool}:
 0
 0
 0
```

If you don't need to preallocate, a good solution is comprehensions. Make a function of the index for creating your boundary condition, e.g.:

```
function my_BC(i)
    out = createBC(m)
    out.left.a[:] = 0.0
    out.left.b[:] = 1.0
    out.left.c[:] = c_left[i]
    return out
end
```

and then simply do

```
[my_BC(i) for i in 1:n_comp]
```